# Input focus in nested navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a master detail tablet view layout in Flutter and running into a bug or something.

### Pseudo layout

```
Scaffold
-- Column
---- Navigator => Container => Input (works)
---- Container => Input (no focus)
```

### Gist

I created a gist to illustrate the problem:
https://gist.github.com/markmooibroek/3459f73bbd89deefeb488060f5bfd87e

### Video

And a video that shows the bugged behaviour. The second input (below) is not getting focussed properly.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1412238/58686402-0507e700-837f-11e9-977d-c16e7a858f27.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you're using nested MaterialApps. A workaround could be to use `FocusScope` and a `FocusScopeNode`. This would allow you to gain focus in other MaterialApps that overlap your main one. This is also the case when using a TextField on an Overlay widget.

So wrap things like shown:

```
FocusScope(
   node : FocusScopeNode(),
   child : return Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Input"),
                ),
              ),
            );
)
```

This should allow you to gain focus in that screen.

Comment: Thanks alot, im not using a separate MaterialApp, but just the Navigator class. But wrapping my 2nd input in a separate FosucScope seems to be working!

Comment: I'm betting each focus scope is related to the Navigator it's in since a MaterialApp is really just a constructor for a bunch of different things – like Navigators. Which would explain why this worked for you. Happy to help.